# Maass forms of higher weight for GL(3)

Tags: automorphic-forms, maass-forms

In the case of $GL(2)$ there is a notion of Maass form of weight $k$, precisely they are eigenfunctions of the weight $k$ Laplacian operator, $\Delta_k$ (taken from "Automorphic forms and represenations" by Bump).

In the case of $GL(3)$, Maass forms are defined as simultaneous eigenfunctions of two differential operators $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$ (One can refer Goldfeld's automorphic forms book). I presume these are "weight 0" Maass forms.

> **My question** : Is there a notion of weight $k$ Maass form for $GL(3)$?

Thank you.

Comment: In higher rank one should probably replace the notion of weight by the notion of having a certain specific $K$-type. Maybe the paper 'Weights, raising and lowering operators, and K-types for automorphic forms on SL(3,R)'  by J- Buttcane and S. D. Miller sheds some light on this.

Comment: Ah yes, that is a very nice way to look at this @WindomEarle. I shall take a look at the paper.

Comment: There are no holomorphic discrete series on GL(n,R) for n > 2.  If you want holomorphy in higher rank, you need to work with other groups.

Comment: @kimball I am not looking for holomorphicity. The forms that I am looking for are Eigen functions of certain differential operators. I guess I am looking for an analogue of the "weight k" Laplacian for higher rank...

Comment: Note that $\Delta_k$ is an operator on the upper half plane. If you think about the Maaß forms as functions on $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with a certain transformation behaviour with respect to $SO(2)$ then the differential operator in Question will simply be the Casimir operator.

Comment: @WindomEarle I didn’t quite get what you meant. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I can try. Let $G=SL(2,R)$, $K=SO(2)$ and $C$ the Casimir operator for $G$. We now fix a representation $(\sigma,V)$ of $K$. (We know that $V$ is one dimensional and $\sigma$ acts by multiplication with $e^{2\pi i k \cdot}$ in suitable coordinates.) Then we can consider eigenfunctions $F\colon \mathbb{C}\to V$ of $C$ that satisfy $F(gk)=\sigma(k)F(g)$ for all $g\in G$ and all $k\in K$. In our particular case (since V is one dimensional) we can descent $F$ to a function on $\mathbb{H}$. Pushing the Casimir operator through this descent will give you exactly the $k$-Laplace operator $\Delta_k$.

Comment: @WindomEarle Thank you, this is much clearer now. But I am not sure this construction works for $n=3$ say. Of the top of my head, I am not sure the maximal compact subgroup of $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ is Abelian. But anyway, I think I have enough to dig deeper.

Comment: The maximal compact subgroup (denote it by $K$ again) of $G=SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ is not abelian which makes things more complicated. The point I wanted to make is that instead of working with functions on the symmetric space $G/K$ one should work with functions on $G$ that have a prescribed transformation behaviour with respect to $K$. The differential operators you are interested in will be the generators of the centre of the universal enveloping algebra. If the prescribed transformation behaviour is trivial the functions of course descent to $G/K$ and you end up with the $\Delta_i$'s.